# Simplest Way to Stream Data to Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, stream, amazon-redshift, amazon-sqs

We are migrating and refactoring some services to AWS and need to verify the accounting information matches the legacy system before we switch over. We do call tracking/analytics and effectively have a stream of call metadata coming into a SNS/SQS processing system. We want to temporarily write the output someplace to compare against the legacy system and identify any discrepancies. This is throw away work, so we want to keep it simple/cheap.

Kinesis to Redshift, using the new Streaming Ingestion is one way to do this. The engineer in me likes this way. However, the simplest thing I can think of is to create an S3 bucket and create 1 file per event (call), and ingest to Redshift from there. Neither option will be expensive at our usage levels, but S3 is very, very inexpensive.

My question is if there is any reason not to have 1 record per S3 file (batching is the typical use case it seems) for ingest to Redshift? We'll generate about 100K records/day, so we're far from big in today's standards.

Cheers!
Rich

Comment: I understand what Bill is saying, but if it is a one time deal, why not use Amazon Athena to do those checks? You do not need to move the data, and you can query the data straight from S3, you don't have to move it. Alternatively, you can use Redshift Spectrum if you want to go with Redshift: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c-using-spectrum.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this option a bit more. We'll have this running for probably a month or two as we build out all the features and work through any bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, don't do this if there is a large amount of data or put differently if you have a very large number of files.  And you don't want to wait hours or days for the data to load.

This is due to the nature of S3, an object store.  The files (objects) written or read from S3 are in a large cluster of computers w/ storage and the location within this cluster is based on hashing of the bucket and key.  This lookup takes on the order of .5 sec to perform (request for data and first bits arriving).  Once the data starts to flow it moves at a reasonably high rate.

When you go to load these many, many very small files the majority of time will be taken up by addressing the object with a very small amount of time moving the data.  While Redshift can read objects from S3 in parallel this parallelism is limited by the number of slices in the cluster.  Moving a few hundred bytes in .5 sec is a bandwidth that harkens back to the 1980s.

To gain the full available bandwidth from S3 the files stored should be at least 100MB and ideally 1GB in size.  Then the time to address the object is insignificant wrt the data transfer time.  This reality will be true when reading data no matter what tool doing the reading.  Writing files isn't an issue since the data is cached before the final location in the S3 cluster is determined.

You will want to combine your records into larger objects in S3.

BTW a single object isn't ideal either as this won't allow for Redshift to read the data in parallel.  Parallel reading can speed up the load by a factor equal to the number of slices in the Redshift cluster (2 to few hundred).  A meaningful improvement.  You can on the other hand have a nearly unlimited number of objects in S3 which can tank just about all load performance.

Comment: This is super informative, especially highlighting the 0.5/s per file address overhead. At 100k/day I suppose we could in theory get this to work, but it's not worth the risk of gotchas hitting us. If you have any thoughts on streaming ingestion for this application, I'd love to here them. Thanks for your time!

Comment: My advice would be to look at the existing patterns that are working.  Either to deploy as a service or create your own solution based on these patterns.  The one that comes to mind is Kinesis Firehose.  See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/what-is-this-service.html This service takes individual data records and combines them into transformed S3 "batches".  Notice that it doesn't use the incoming records stored to S3 as the source of these batches - it writes both in parallel - as this avoids the read latency issue.

Comment: The other way to go is to "live with it".  At 100K records a day and let's say 8 slices, this comes out to ~6K seconds per day waiting for S3.  If you load Redshift every hour then this is less than 5min per hour spent waiting on S3.  It's not great from a data timeliness POV but maybe you can live with it.  Just remember that this won't scale - if your data goes up 10X then you are spending about an hour waiting for an hourly load to happen.  I don't recommend this approach but for a throw away project it might be acceptable.

Comment: If it was me I'd just hook SNS up to Kinesis Firehose (a documented path) and just have Firehose load Redshift.  This might be overkill for you (and cost a bit) but if it is just for a short time the price is likely acceptable and there is less "throw away" work to be done.